# Making a list of shades and styles for plots

Tags: python, numpy

For a section of a much larger program that generates plots, I am creating a list of styles that I can pull from to create a consistent format from plot-to-plot. It works as follows

I have a list of colors `shade = ['k','m']` and a list of styles `style = ['--', ':','-','.']` that I am concatenating to get the desired list `Colors= [['k--', 'k:', 'k-', 'k.'], ['m--', 'm:', 'm-', 'm.']]`. I am achieving this with the following nested loop (t and phi are not always necessarily the same size but for example sake they are here)

```
import numpy as np

t = np.linspace(0,1,24)
phi = np.linspace(0,1,24)

shade = ['k','m']
style = ['--', ':','-','.']
Colors = []

for i in shade:
    cs = []
    for j in style:
        for k in range(int(len(t)/len(phi))):
            cs.append(i+j)
    Colors.append(cs)

print(Colors)
```

This is fine and works, plus it is a small operation so I'm not worried about the run-time of it, I am just tired of looking at such a big loop that could probably be written in one line.

Comment: [itertools.product](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The inner for loop over the `range` is virtually useless, since it only ever executes once. Hence it can be dropped and your code can be condensed to one nested list comprehension.

```py
shades = ['k','m']
styles = ['--', ':','-','.']
colors = [[shade+style for style in styles] for shade in shades]

print(colors)
```

Comment: The `range`  loop accounts for if t and phi are not the same size ie: len(t) -> 24, len(phi) -> 12 (which is sometimes necessary in the program), but from here I can reincorporate it into your solution. Thanks for the help!